# How to interpret results from R anova in quantile regression?

Tags: r, quantile-regression

Here is a sample output:

```
anova(fit1,fit2);
Quantile Regression Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: op ~ inp1 + inp2 + inp3 + inp4 + inp5 + inp6 + inp7 + inp8 + inp9
Joint Test of Equality of Slopes: tau in {  0.15 0.3  }

  Df Resid Df F value Pr(>F)
1  9     1337  0.5256 0.8568

Warning messages:
1: In summary.rq(x, se = "nid", covariance = TRUE) : 93 non-positive fis
2: In summary.rq(x, se = "nid", covariance = TRUE) : 138 non-positive fis
```

How to interpret the above results??
Does the `anova()` function give the best model, for `tau=0.15` vs. `tau=0.3`?

Comment: I think it would help to tell people what fit1 and fit2 are

Answer (score 3):

The interpretation of the result of a joint test of equality of slopes is that overall, the effect of the entire set of coefficients is uniform across quantiles.

Understand that this is not a test of the performance of your two models, it simply tests whether slope coefficients of those models, from several quantiles, can be considered not different.